# Import an OpenSSL ECDSA PEM private key and sign it

Tags: c#, openssl, cryptography, ecdsa

To generate a private and public key with OpenSSL I have run

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -out private-key.pem
openssl ec -in private-key.pem -out public-key.pem -pubout
```

I upload the public key to the remote server. Then import the `private-key.pem` to a .Net Framework (it has to be .Net Framework) C# service to use it to sign an API payload:

```
public string LoadFromCng(byte[] request, string privateKeyFile)
{
    CngKey cng = CngKey.Open(privateKeyFile);

    // Sign the request body with the private key.
    ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(cng);
    byte[] signedRequest = dsa.SignData(request, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signedRequest);
}
```

With `privateKeyFile = private-key.pem` the above code gives `Keyset does not exist`

If I use `mkcert` and run  `mkcert -ecdsa -pkcs12 private-key.pem` it generates a PKCS#12 key called `private-key.pem.p12` and then:

```
public string LoadFromX509(byte[] request, string privateKeyFile)
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyFile, "changeit");
    var key = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
    byte[] signedRequest = key.SignData(request, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signedRequest);
}
```

With `privateKeyFile = private-key.pem.p12` the above code appears to sign the request, but the API response is `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request` which means the API provider can't decode the payload from the `public key`.

I get the same 400 error when going through the [cheat sheet here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenSSL/Creating-Elliptical-Curve-Keys-using-OpenSSL) and creating an X509 pfx certificate.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key private-key.pem -out cert.pem -days 360
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private-key.pem -in cert.pem -out cert.pfx
```

The method above appears to sign the payload but the provider responds with a 400.

The suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740429/how-to-compute-the-ecdsa-signature-using-a-p-256-key-in-a-pem-file-using-c-net?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160232/how-do-i-load-an-openssl-ecdsa-key-into-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754685/how-do-i-use-a-private-key-in-c-cannot-find-the-requested-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462064/associate-a-private-key-with-the-x509certificate2-class-in-net?noredirect=1&lq=1) and others have not worked.

I can't use Net Core or NET 5 so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933396/how-to-load-private-ecdsa-key-es256-in-c) doesn't work either. The `ImportPkcs8PrivateKey` method is not available in Net Framework.

If I try and use Bouncy Castle per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346200/reading-pem-rsa-public-key-only-using-bouncy-castle) I get `Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPrivateKeyParameters' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters'`

Comment: One problem is that we don't know exactly what the server expects. Which server are you trying to connect to? Where are the protocol specifications? Without that you're firing shots in the blind. You seem to be able to sign, so the problem must exist somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The first OpenSSL statement creates an EC parameter file *private-key.pem*, which contains, among others, a PEM encoded private EC key in SEC1 format.

With .NET Framework the easiest way is to use BouncyCastle for key import. BouncyCastle also supports the ASN.1/DER format and the IEEE P1363 (r|s) format for EC signatures.

The following code imports a PEM encoded private EC key in SEC1 format and signs a message.

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
...
string pkcs8 =  @"-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
                MHQCAQEEIMmN/YG6BtIqm9eAcYtKdcbJosNKbB76vGMTSltPLNiioAcGBSuBBAAK
                oUQDQgAESGnGxuBPdrwv1TkJEorsaNk74+ZFh2jzww2SpLTqQqkvOf5IP6fuODS/
                hzztSBpsBpX9LUZh8TYHX0HRMagkaA==
                -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";

TextReader privateKeyTextReader = new StringReader(pkcs8);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair privateKeyParams = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(privateKeyTextReader).ReadObject();

byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withECDSA"); // ASN.1/DER format
//ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withPLAIN-ECDSA"); // r|s format
signer.Init(true, privateKeyParams.Private);
signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
Console.WriteLine(Hex.ToHexString(signature)); // 3046022100967c2e890d933c75468dceaf61152add41f143568dcb967583e1b307a0b495e30221008f6837c0d9cc01fc7bfe54ed5b6267fd3e64c2d3ff771e72762f24c20071c454
```